# 'notin' used within a 'where' statement syntax in PROC PROBIT

Tags: sas

I'm working with [some one else's code](https://xkcd.com/1513/) which contains the following instance of `PROC PROBIT`.

```
proc probit data = mortality  order=data;
   where group notin (9);
   class survive;
   model survive =log_dose / D = LOGISTIC INVERSECL;
   ods output /*logprobitanalysis=logprobliv_dose*/ probitanalysis=probliv_dose;
RUN;
```

What function does the `(9)` serve in the `where` statement?

I'm scouring documentation, but not having much luck finding an explanation.  Is it native to the `where` statement?  Or, does the `order=` option alter the capabilities of `where` within `proc probit`?  I assume that `notin` is a variable, but it's not entirely clear to me from the code.  Is `notin` some obscure keyword for `not in (list)`?

(Un)Fortunately, the author is no longer with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOTIN` is the same as `NOT IN`.  I assume SAS sees `NOT` and applies it as a modifier for what comes next, if what comes next is an operator.

So this works:

```
data test;
do group=1 to 9;
    output;
end;
run;

data want;
set test;
where group notin (1,9);
run;
```

Leaving you with group in {2,3,...,8}

Comment: Do you know of anywhere that this is documented?

Comment: I do not.  It is probably something in the syntax checker trying to help people who are too lazy or forget to hit the space bar...